# Is there a relationship between these integrals?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If this is given:
$$\int_0^1f(x)dx=1$$
Then is there anything else we can say about:
$$\int_0^1xf(x)dx \;\;\;\;\; \text{ or } \;\;\;\;\;  \int_0^1x^2f(x)dx$$

Comment: Since $\{1, x, x^2, \cdots \}$ forms a basis of $L^1[0, 1]$, there is nothing that we can say about those integrals as we may assign arbitrary values to them and then find a suitable integrable function $f$ yielding those values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. Then
$$
\int_0^1f(x)dx=\frac{a}3+\frac{b}2+c,
$$
$$
\int_0^1xf(x)dx=\frac{a}4+\frac{b}3+\frac{c}2,
$$
$$
\int_0^1x^2f(x)dx=\frac{a}5+\frac{b}4+\frac{c}3.
$$
You get a determined system of three equations on three unknowns. That means that for any values that you choose, you will be able to find coefficients $a,b,c$ such that the three integrals will take exactly those values.

In all, there is absolutely no general relation between the values of those integrals.

Answer (score 2):

If in addition $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, $f(x)$ is the probability density function for a random variable $X$ with values in $[0,1]$, while $E[X] = \int_0^1 x f(x)\ dx$ and $E[X^2] = \int_0^1 x^2 f(x)\ dx$.  In that case $0 \le E[X] \le \sqrt{E[X^2]} \le 1$.